# Selenium RC -html suite hangs on "Preparing Firefox profile..."

Tags: firefox, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, htmlsuite

I'm having some trouble when I execute the following command in cmd windows 8;

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.konga.com" "C:\Users\Tunji\Desktop\SeleniumTestsCoreFunctionality\DeliveryWidgetTest.html" "C:\Users\Tunji\Desktop\SeleniumTestsCoreFunctionality\results.html" -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\Users\Tunji\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\0srebkp2.selenium"
```

Output:

1. 19:00:37.664 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 23.25-b01

   19:00:37.665 INFO - OS: Windows 8 6.2 amd64

   19:00:37.667 INFO - v1.0-SNAPSHOT [1123], with Core v1.0-SNAPSHOT [2101]

   19:00:37.747 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x

   19:00:37.749 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]

   19:00:37.750 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]

   19:00:37.750 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]

   19:00:37.757 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444

   19:00:37.757 INFO - Started org.mortbay.jetty.Server@3ff9f663

   19:00:38.310 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...

It hangs at line 10 when I execute this same command with "*firefox" or "*chrome"

Please **HELP**!

Firefox version 23.0.1

Windows 8

Selenium - selenium.rc.version=1.0

Answer (score 1):

Download Selenium RC version 2.35.0 and Try this. Let me know it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Prashant, it worked! 
However after the browser launched it still didn't execute my test. Any Ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after upgrading to Firefox 38. Going back to 37 solved the problem for me.